# urlInspection - Google Search Console API - quota issue

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

I've been trying to get Indexation Status from `https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlInspection/index:inspect` API. The 1st request worked. The 2nd, returned:

```
{'error': {'code': 429, 'message': 'Quota exceeded for sc-domain:mydomain.com.', 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED'}}
```

After a while, got another one that worked, then all of them are 429s. As you can see here, I've only made 30 requests, 93% of them are 429s check screen.

Any idea why?

I've tried getting different credentials. Nothing happened.